# Why does the "lo" interface not have a MAC address

Tags: networking, localhost

I'm trying to understand why the loopback does not have a mac address. Or if it does, is it the same as that of my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it doesn't need one.
MACs (Machine Address Code)s are used at the lowest level of ethernet traffic, and only within one LAN (Local Area Network) and help direct traffic around within it. It simply isn't needed on a local network interface because packets are are handled internally.

Comment: Someone tried to submit an edit to this question saying that MAC stands for "Media Access Control" and not "Machine Address Code". I disagree and rejected the edit. "Media Access Control" is some new term that some like to use, but the original, acronym was for "Machine Address Code".